# VIM abbreviation stops working: how to debug

Tags: vim

I believe some addition of plugins has made my vim not responding to predefined abbreviations in my vimrc, like

```
iab INP import numpy as np
```

I know I could possibly track it down by going thru the changes I've made since the last time it worked, but is there a simple way to debug this, just as ppl would do when they try to find out what plugin or command had double-booked a keymapping using `verbose map`?

**EDIT**

the culprit is the `auto-pairs` plugin --- but the question is still unresolved: is there a way to debug the `iab` mapping problem efficiently? `verbose iab INP` apparently failed to notify me the `abbr` was removed by the plugin.

Comment: Do you have an autoclosing plugin?

Comment: @romainl bravo! you nailed it! it's the `auto-pairs` plugin! any idea on how to allow the co-existence of `abbr` and `auto-pairs`?

Comment: @romainl I switched from `auto-pairs` to `vim-autoclose` then the `abbr` works. However it'll be still useful if I can debug the loss of `abbr` in an agnostic way...

Comment: `:verbose imap` is the right way to debug a genuine `abbr` problem but your problem is not strictly an `abbr` one: AFAIK, all autoclosing plugins use `imap`s to work their magic and they all do that in slightly different ways. The most aggressive ones will prevent abbreviations from working by eating your `<space>`s, others won't. You'll need to review their code to compare their methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:verbose` modifier when checking the current definition:

```
:verbose iab INP
```

Unfortunately, if the abbreviation has been deleted, then this will not tell you anything.

Comment: I tried that already and it showed the `abbr` was there and was last set by my `vimrc` despite the dysfunctioning.

Comment: Then maybe we need a more detailed description of what "dysfunctioning" means.

Comment: sure, although as of now all I know is the `INP` combination won't expand to `import numpy as np`

Comment: The basics are (1) What did you do? (2) What did you expect to get? (3) What did you actually get?

Comment: as I described in the question, I'm looking for an efficient way of debugging the abbr-not-working problem without the need to conditionally removing my vimrc settings. So 1) I did nothing except for trying the verbose mode 2) N/A 3) N/A.

Comment: I am trying to understand what is going wrong.  If you type "INP" in Insert mode, that would be an answer to (1).  In that case, I think you would have an answer to (2) and (3).  I am also interested in what happens if you type "INP space".  What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Oh I see. you are talking about the symptoms of my problem...yeah, INP+<CR> won't do anything, but INP+<SPACE> did expand correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I had a problem with ab when had multiline abbreviation. Vim expected whitespace after synonym and I've used a newline.